# Syntax error from Email template using if else and checkbox

Tags: netsuite

Hello and thank you for your help in advance.

My task is a simple one, I have a working workflow in netsuite based on a transaction (Purchase Order).  In the email template I want to print a field in the body of an email template if a checkbox is checked, and not print it if its unchecked.  This is my first foray into using free marker so I'm at ground zero.

I get a malformed tag syntax error.  I've been researching this but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.  In the documentation I've found in free marker, this seems like it should work. but alas no.

I've tried:

> <#if transaction.custbody72 ==1 >
>
> ${transaction.custbody32}
>
> </#if>

also tried == true, TRUE, True, is true etc.

Answer (score 0):

Netsuite returns checkbox values as "T" or "F" so

```
<#if transaction.custbody72 == "T">
```

They also do that for all Suitescript 1 record field and search results
In SS2 you still use 'T' and 'F' for search criteria for for freemarker templates called from SS2 scripts but you get booleans from record field values and search results.